# Assigning global access rule for a directory's sub-repositories with gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite, access-rules

I am organizing every user's repositories under directory named as the user's alias; For example if i have a user named `dariush` and he has 3 repos named `repo1`, `repo2` and `repo3`.The directory structure of dariush's repos will be something like below:

```
~/repositories/
      |_ dariush
            |_ repo1.git
            |_ repo2.git
            |_ repo3.git
```

The topic which discussed [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) suggests that for every each repository of our example user `dariush` above, I define an access rule in `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` as below:

```
repo dariush/repo1
      RW+    =   dariush

repo dariush/repo2
     RW+     =   dariush

repo dariush/repo3
     RW+     =   dariush
```

OR

```
@dariush_repos = dariush/repo1 dariush/repo2 dariush/repo3

repo @dariush_repos
     RW+     =   dariush
```

But it makes sense if i want to try to use regex like below to assign access rules

```
repo dariush/.+
     RW+     =   dariush
```

which means for every repositories under directory `~/repositories/dariush` apply the following rules.

But it is not working!!

### My quesions

1. Is it possible to do such thing i.e **using regex** like `repo dariush/.+` to define rules, if so what am i doing wrong?
2. If the question #1 is not possible is there any other **more convenient** way to accomplish such matter?

Thanks in advance.